# Java RMI error in HP BSAE 2.0 configuration migration log

Tags: debugging, rmi, hpsa

I'm attempting to track this issue with HP's Enterprise Support as well, but am not familiar with Java's RMI context, and am hoping the community can provide some assistance, too.

Context: recently upgraded the reporting tool for HP's BSA (Business Service Automation) Suite from SAR (Service Automation Reporting) 7.81 to BSAE (BSA Essentials) 2.0.

In the process, one of the steps is to migrate previously-used external user authentication to the new reporting tool. When running that migration script, the following Java error stack is dumped:

```
14:57:25,316 DEBUG [InvokeCommand] Using params: /var/opt/opsware/omdb/tmp/sar-aaa-migrate-1279033044903.xml
14:57:26,512 ERROR [Twiddle] Exec failed
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opsware.cmdb.security.data.AAADataImportException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:227)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPInvoker_Stub.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.interfaces.JRMPInvokerProxy.invoke(JRMPInvokerProxy.java:133)
at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invokeInvoker(InvokerInterceptor.java:365)
at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invoke(InvokerInterceptor.java:197)
at org.jboss.jmx.connector.invoker.client.InvokerAdaptorClientInterceptor.invoke(InvokerAdaptorClientInterceptor.java:66)
at org.jboss.proxy.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:70)
at org.jboss.proxy.ClientMethodInterceptor.invoke(ClientMethodInterceptor.java:74)
at org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:100)
at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.console.twiddle.command.InvokeCommand.invoke(InvokeCommand.java:235)
at org.jboss.console.twiddle.command.InvokeCommand.execute(InvokeCommand.java:291)
at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle.main(Twiddle.java:306)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opsware.cmdb.security.data.AAADataImportException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:375)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:165)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:247)
at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:197)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1575)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:225)
... 13 more
```

Understanding that I have 0 access to the code base, is there a place I can start to look for what may be causing the RMI failures, or will this need to be handled exclusively through the vendor?

Thanks for any assistance/pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the root cause on this error is related to issues with both the documented upgrade process from SAR to BSAE *and* the dataminer on the HPSA server attempting to re-mine the same data chunks over and over again.

The fix for this is to do a complete back-out of BSAE to a blank server, then doing a clean install.

Sadly, that means all historical data is lost in the process :-|